# How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have 6 buttons that I want to be attached to the same handler. How can I do this?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I can double click the buttons on the designer view and generate 6 stubs, but why would I want to do that when I can just subscribe the buttons to a single event.

Comment: rather than double-click, drop the list down and select the existing handler...

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly normal (beginner) question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you subscribe to the event on a button, it's just a standard event handler:

```
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
```

You can use the same code to add handlers for every button:

```
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
button2.Click += myEventHandler;
button3.Click += myEventHandler;
button4.Click += myEventHandler;
button5.Click += myEventHandler;
button6.Click += myEventHandler;
```

This will cause your handler in `myEventHandler` to be run when any of the buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 40):

You can attach the same event to multiple buttons by binding the same method to each buttons click event

```
myButton1.Click += new MyButtonClick;
myButton2.Click += new MyButtonClick;
myButton3.Click += new MyButtonClick;
myButton4.Click += new MyButtonClick;
myButton5.Click += new MyButtonClick;
myButton6.Click += new MyButtonClick;

void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    //here you can check which button was clicked by the sender
}
```

Comment: I have used CommandName and CommandArgument to identify the different buttons linked to same onclick event. I gave +1 for u.

Comment: I had to remove the new keyword to make this work.

Answer (score 14):

Just wire the buttons to the same event:

```
myButton1.Click += Button_Click;
myButton2.Click += Button_Click;
myButton3.Click += Button_Click;
...
```

And handle the buttons accordingly:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;

    switch (buttonText)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `sender` object contains the reference to the button which caused the Click event. You can cast it back to `Button`, and access whatever property you need to distinguish the actual button.

Comment: The cast ended up with missing assembly information.

Answer (score 5):

How to see which button was pressed:

Use the `sender`

```
Button myButton = (Button)sender;
```

`sender` is a parameter of type `object` in your event handler.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of double clicking the event in the designer you can paste the name of the event handler to to the event in the designer property grid.

Answer (score 2):

```
myButton1.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
myButton2.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
myButton3.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
myButton4.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
myButton5.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
myButton6.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtonClick);

public void MyButtonClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
                switch ((sender as Button).Name)
                {
                case "button1":
                    //actions
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    //actions
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
               }
}
```

Comment: It says "The type or name space for button could not be found."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I use this and it looks pretty simple

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Just give both buttons the same click event

Answer (score 0):

```html
 button1.Click += button_Click;
 button2.Click += button_Click;

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == button1)
            {
                this.Text = "1";
            }
            else if (sender == button2)
            {
                this.Text = "2";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit?

Answer (score -1):

In main.axml add this to all the buttons

```
android:clickable="whateveryoulike"
```

and all the buttons need to have the same id

in the  MainActivity

```
[Java.Interop.Export("whateveryoulike")]
void whateveryoulike2(View v){
Button button=(Button) v;
//your code here
}
```

the name of the method doesnt matter