# Iterating through buttons and their return values

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

Imagine you have buttons and everytime you click on one,it writes a text to a textbox.

ie:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button41.Click
        textbox.Text &= "1"
    End Sub
```

And lets say you have 10 of these buttons as numbers (0-9 for example.)Instead of handling the click events of these buttons one by one (buttonxclickevent handles textbox.text = x for example);is there a more elegant way to iterate throught these buttons and events?

Comment: Why is this tagged with the java keyword?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according

Comment: Tagged as C# and Java and provides VB/VB.NET code?

Comment: The method could handle more than one button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have shown VB.NET code, i'll answer with VB.NET. You could use one handler for all:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        For Each btn In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf buttonClicked
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        TextBox1.Text &= "1"
    End Sub

End Class
```

[`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) filters and casts, so the result is an `IEnumerable(Of Button)`.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Let the class implements the `ActionListener`

**-** Override the `actionPerformed()` **method** like this to identify the button and type the message accordingly into the `JTextField`.

```
JButton b1;
JButton b2;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == b1) {
      // Do something...
   }
   if (e.getSource() == b2) {
      // Do something else...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in this way :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
        Dim b As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Label1.Text = b.ID
End Sub
```