# Event to enable apply button

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, apply

An apply button on my standard winform is disabled on loading and I want to enable it, if a state of any other control changes (checkboxes, radioboxes, textboxes etc.)

So I could go through the events of every single control and enable the button there but I want to know if there is an easier way to do it, like a global event.

**Edit**
To clarify: I'm looking for a method where I havn't to do something with every single control. So that I can add more controls at a later point and don't have to care about them ...

Comment: For future reference, make sure you the question you're asking isn't a duplicate of another one. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according) previous SO question.

Comment: I'm looking for a method for not having it to do for every single control ... so this question is actually not a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't explicitly state that you want to do it for _every_ control, you asked if there was something like a "global event". If that's not what you're actually looking for you should rephrase the question in a manner that's more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be nitpicky but it's important that if you want quality answers that people are able to understand what your goal is in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: Its a good advice after I understand what you mean (I recently updated the question) ... but it was my 1st time on stack overflow ... so be soft :P

Comment: Please see my edited answer and let me know if this properly addresses your issue/question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your edit I've revised my answer to include the functionality you desire.

First you need a generic event handler that should look something like this:

```
void MyHandler(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Where button1 is the button you wish to enable.

Then you're going to need a recursive method to not only iterate through your `Form.Controls`, but any container type controls contained in there as well. I've included handling of some common container controls as well as some basic data entry controls:

```
void AddEvents(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection Controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        if (c is GroupBox)
        {
            AddEvents(((GroupBox)c).Controls);
        }
        else if (c is Panel)
        {
            AddEvents(((Panel)c).Controls);
        }
        //Expand this series of if...else... to include any 
        //other type of container control
        else if (c is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)c).TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyHandler);
        }
        else if (c is RichTextBox)
        {
            ((RichTextBox)c).TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyHandler);
        }
        else if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)c).CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(MyHandler);
        }
        else if (c is DateTimePicker)
        {
            ((DateTimePicker)c).ValueChanged += new EventHandler(MyHandler);
        }
        //Expand this to include any other type of controls your form 
        //has that you need to add the event to
    }
}
```

The first part of the `if else` block checks to see if the `control` is of a type that contains other controls. If it is it then [recursively](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion) calls the AddEvents method with the new `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection` contained in that `control`.

The second part of the `if else` block checks what type of control c is so that it can be appropriately [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the correct type, and therefore utilize the correct event. If we are able to determine our control type at this point, the generic event created earlier is added as a handler.

Last, you need to call this method. The two best places would probably be either in your constructor or on the `Form.Load` event. The best place to put it will depend on your specific circumstances. I chose to use my constructor for simplicity, which now looks like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddEvents(this.Controls);
}
```

And that should be all you need to iterate your controls and add the generic event handler. This code is from an actual project I created and I have tested it to ensure it's proper functionality.

**EDIT:** I've also just tested this using `control`s inside of a `GroupBox` inside of a `Panel` inside of a `GroupBox` inside of a `Panel` that's on a `Form`. This is where the usefulness of utilizing recursion comes in. You don't need to know to exact depth of nesting so long as you properly set up your `if...else...` blocks. It will go as deep as it needs to without needing to use nested loops and knowing the exact depth.

**EDIT2:** As a side note, this method could also be used on a more granular level. Let's say you have multiple `GroupBox` controls and you wish to only add the event handler to controls in "grpBox1". You could call `AddEvents(grpBox1.Controls)` instead of `AddEvents(this.Controls)` and this would only apply the event handler to controls contained in `grpBox1`.

**EDIT3:** As onemancat has pointed out in the comments, it's not entirely necessary to actually check if the control is a `GroupBox` or a `Panel` etc. because all controls inherit from the base class `Control` which has a `Controls` property. You simply could check if the `Control` contains other controls by saying `if (c.Controls.Count > 0) AddEvents(c.Controls);` however, in a situation where one wants to choose which container controls to iterate, it would be necessary to check the type as I have in my example. If it's not necessary to be this granular it does make more sense to check the count and never bother with type checking or casting.

Comment: I also have to do that for every single checkbox, havn't I?

Comment: @lorus There are ways to iterate through a `Form`'s controls, as onemancat has stated, and with recursion it's also possible to iterate through the controls of a container control (`GroupBox`, `Panel` etc.). onemancat's answer is very close to what you're looking for so I'm going to give them a chance to edit their answer before I completely get rid of mine and post a new one. This does answer your question about a "global event", however.

Comment: @lorus You will probably have to make some minor modifications where I have the comments in the `AddEvents` block but this should definitely provide the building blocks you need. I have something _similar_ to this in a class library because it can be very useful and only requires minor modification for the various places it can be used. I definitely recommend you read the article on recursion I linked to in my answer and do some research on it because it's a great tool for things like this.

Comment: @lorus You should also do some research on [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx) and [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(v=vs.80).aspx) because that's what allows us to create this generic handler. Everything in C# inherits from `Object` and polymorphism is what allows us to cast things to an `object` and back again like you see in event handlers. All event arguments _should_ also inherit from `EventArgs` which should allow us to use polymorphism to implicitly cast all types of event arguments back to `EventArgs`

Comment: You dont need to look for GroupBox etc, just any Control that has child controls...can't believe I didn't get any credit for my answer lol

Comment: @onemancat true you could just check the count of `Control.Controls` but your answer still didn't cover the recursion to iterate through those controls

Comment: @onemancat I chose to take a more granular approach because there may be a situation where someone wants to only iterate through the controls in a `Panel` and not a `GroupBox` or something similar.

Comment: @onemancat I've updated my answer to include this information and gave you an honorable mention for pointing this out, as this is definitely useful information.

Comment: If validation is performed on fields (and it usually should be), then Validated may be the most appropriate handler for checking for Apply.

Answer (score 1):

If this is going to be a common theme in your application, you could create some reusable code that recursively examines all controls of a form, and wires the event handler up.  You could put it right after InitiaizeComponent();

```
        // Programmatically wire up all Changed events to enable the button
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is CheckBox)
            {
                ((CheckBox)ctl).CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Button_Enable);
            }
            else if (ctl is RadioButton)
            {
                ((RadioButton)ctl).CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Button_Enable);
            }
            // Here, wire up all other control types you'd like the button to respond to
        }
```

Then, in the handler, you enable the button:

```
void Button_Enable(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

You could call this method on many forms to create a consistent UI for the user.  The advantage of this approach is that as you add new controls to a form, you (or the next developer) don't have to remember to wire up the change event to the button being enabled, it will happen automatically.

Comment: That looks great! Unfortunately none of the if-statements ever becomes true because ctl never is anything but a GroupBox ... how could I wire into the groupboxes, too?

Comment: You've stated about using recursion but not actually provided code that calls anything recursively. If you structured this answer into a recursive method so that a `control` in a `control` can be set, I think this will provide the answer the OP is looking for. (Example a `Button` inside of a `Panel` won't be set if the controls on the `Panel` are not also iterated.)