# writing one method only for all button's MouseEnter event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I want to show Image on MouseEnter event of button control(I have 6 buttons) ,I can use below code for each button

```
void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
          }
```

but I Don't want to write it for each buttons enter event ,and hence trying to make it only on method so can use for each button something like this ,but how do I will select different image for different button via this method than ?

```
void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = (Button)sender;
            this.btn.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.particular image for particular button));
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You register the same event for all buttons.

For example:

```
 btn1.MouseEnter += genericButton_event;
 btn2.MouseEnter += genericButton_event;
```

You add the image to resources for example using the same name as the `button` so you can use the `btn.Name` property. (Something like: btn1.png and btn2.png), and you assign the resource using reflection with the string property "name":

```
private void genericButton_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        btn.BackgroundImage =   new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(). 
            GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources" + btn.Name +".png"));       

    }
```

> You get the bitmap from resources using strings, so you can get the desired background image depending on button name.

Comment: I used it like this `btn.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
                GetManifestResourceStream("Properties.Resources" + btn.Name + ".png"));` showing me this error `Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.` I have also changed name as per the button

Comment: You have to use full application namespace. Add your project name before the Properties.Resources. Try until you get it. I'm using this code in a lot of winforms forms.

Comment: How could I check what stream I am getting for `GetManifestResourceStream` ,I tried this `"StudentModule.Properties.Resources" ` but getting same error .

Comment: I would recommend you to stop there while debugging. Then use the debug > inmediate window to try/error until you find the complete namespace of the resource. Maybe your name is different. Or you are using uppercase or something like that. I can assure you this works when you find the proper namespace

Comment: You have to use your projectName.ResourcesName.ImageName. Something like: SportStoreProject.Resources.Image1.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39890/discussion-between-durga-and-carlos-landeras)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Tag` attribute for that. It takes an `object` - so you can put there whatever you want.

Or you could chose which image to display by naming them after the button and searching for the correctly named image.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = <YourImage>; // Here you define which image to show
btn.MouseLeave += btn_MouseLeave;

void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button b = (Button)sender;
     b.BackGroundImage = (System.Drawing.Image)b.Tag;
}
```

Of course you'd have to check if the `Tag` is null.