# Await a button click

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, click, async-await

I use C#.
I want to make a method that will do some stuff and then wait for the user to click one of four buttons. I want something similar to the MessageDialog async method that waits the user to click in this case, "Yes" or "No":

```
private  async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = new MessageDialog("Yes or no?", "Choose");

    x.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", (UICommandInvokeHandler) =>
        {
            // blabla
        }));
    x.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", (UICommandInvokeHandler) =>
        {
            // blabla
        }));

    await x.ShowAsync();
}
```

The problem is that I can't use this method (MessageDialog) because I want 4 options but MessageDialog is up to 3.

EDIT:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // doing some stuff
    Method();
    // doing some other stuff
}

private void Method()
{
    // makes everything in UI invisible
    // then makes the four buttons that were previously invisible, //visible
    // here I want the program to stop and wait the user to press one of //the four buttons
    // and then make the UI visible and the 4 buttons invisibl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message Dialog` represents a dialog in the WinRT framework. It supports only 3 buttons to make it usable on smaller screens. You have no other WinRT options.
You can however create your own "dialog like" UI control, but i wouldn't recommend it.
Maybe You can split your users decisions to 2 message dialogs.

Comment: Ye, I thought of this too, but it's not convinient at all...
I will just make everything else in the UI Visibility.Collapsed
and then make 4 buttons on screen Visibility.Visible
and I want to wait for the user to click one of the four buttons.

Comment: You can do that, but it isn't really an asynchronous operation. I would simply recommend having those buttons target the same `EventHandler` that "collapses" all of them and knows which button was clicked because it's inside the `object sender`

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but can you give me an example with the four buttons and the method?

Comment: Here's a clear stackoverflow example [How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3814234/885318)

Comment: Ok, let's say I make an event handler myEventHandler
and I add all 4 of my buttons:
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
button2.Click += myEventHandler;
button3.Click += myEventHandler;
button4.Click += myEventHandler;

I don't get how will that help in waiting for the user to click one of the 4 buttons... Sorry I'm still a beginner and I'm not sure how to use this..

Comment: `myEventHandler` is the event handler for the Click event on all 4 buttons. If the user clicks any of them `myEventHandler` will be called and a reference to the clicked button will be in the sender parameter. The code in that `myEventHandler` will be called right after the user clicked any of the 4 buttons.

Comment: Alright now I get it I think and it's not really helping with my problem... :/
Maybe I didn't explain it good.

Let's say I have:

    private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //doing some stuff
         Method();     
            //doing some other stuff
        }
private void Method()
{
//makes everything in UI invisible
//then makes the four buttons that were previously invisible, //visible
//here I want the program to stop and wait the user to press one of //the four buttons
//and then make the UI visible and the 4 buttons invisibl
}

Comment: Just split these things in to 2. after `Method` changes the UI it should end and Button_Click should not have any other stuff after it. You should have a different `Button_Click2` method that runs when the 4 buttons are clicked and what it does is "//doing some other stuff". This will act exactly how you described and will be simple

Comment: It could work, yes. But in my case it would be very painfull, because
inside Button_Click there are also some if , and the Method() is in one of them.So the Method is not always supposed to run
and there are some more operations running when you click the button.
If I do what you say I'll have to copy paste all this code to all the buttons (the first one that calls the Method() (but not always) and the other 4)

Comment: So let's say the Method runs because the if is true, how will it wait for click and then check the other ifs? If on the other hand I cut the other ifs and paste to the 4 buttons, when the if of the Method is false the other ifs won't "activate".

Comment: What happens before calling Method should stay where it is. Method should only show the buttons. The 4 buttons have the same Eventhandler so no copy paste is needed and they should do what you want to be done after the user clicked them. If you have actions you want to do both after the 4 buttons are clicked and also after the first one was click, just make a new method and reuse it in both places.

Comment: I guess I'll make like 4 more methods so that I can organise the operations better because after the first if which is for the Method()
there are like more than 100 lines of code and it wouldn't look very good if I copy paste all that all over... So I'll then use your idea with the "second" button... Thanks for your time and help! :) though I was expecting something with less code, but I'm happy anyway because I think this will work! :) Thanks again