# Cleanest way to change a property of the selected entity using a single method? C#

Tags: c#, button

I am interested in having the same mouseover effect (specifically changing the colour of the background) on all of my buttons. However, I am sure there is a more sensible way than using:

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

for each of my buttons. Is there a way I can use one method to apply that effect to every single button?

Asking questions like this is very new to me so if the question is misleading or worded wrong please let me know so I can correct it.

Thank you!

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according).  In your case, rather than handling click, you'd be updating the back colour

Comment: Which technology? WinForms, WPF, web,....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create your own button class that inherits Button?

This way you can handle the behavior in only one place and avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Add this event handler to all your buttons' Enter events:

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

The `sender` parameter is a reference to the object which raised the event - in this case the specific Button.
If you want to be sure that the sender is indeed a Button, you can use something like this:

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
        button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same event to all your buttons, and then you use

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

in order to fire the event for the correct button. It is probably better to make sure that the sender is a button for when you accidentally assign the event to another Control, or you can cast it to a `Control` which BackColor is derived from

Answer (score 0):

Create `events` like this; your `constructor` is a good place to have them.

```
this.Button1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.myButton_Enter);
this.Button2.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.myButton_Enter);
```

Then you only need 1 event.

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button) sender;
    button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

**Source**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984308%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your own class of `Button` as others have suggested and use that (assuming you want this functionality throughout an application rather than on a form).  If you want it just on a form and require little else consistency, you can always create a recursive function that sifts through all of the controls on your form and adds the handler dynamically.  E.g.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitCustomButtons();
    }

    private void InitCustomButtons()
    {
        this.InitCustomButtonsRecursive(this);
    }

    private void InitCustomButtonsRecursive(Control container)
    {
        if (container is Button)
        {
            container.Enter += ColorButtonOnEnter;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < container.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            var control = container.Controls[i];
            InitCustomButtonsRecursive(control);
        }
    }

    private void ColorButtonOnEnter(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

However, if I understand your desired intent, you may want to

1. Store the original color of the background color and
2. Restore it

E.g.:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitCustomButtons();
    }

    private void InitCustomButtons()
    {
        this.InitCustomButtonsRecursive(this);
    }

    private Dictionary<Button, Color> _originalColors = new Dictionary<Button, Color>(); 

    private void InitCustomButtonsRecursive(Control container)
    {
        if (container is Button)
        {
            container.MouseEnter += ColorButtonEnter;
            container.MouseLeave += ColorButtonLeave;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < container.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            var control = container.Controls[i];
            InitCustomButtonsRecursive(control);
        }
    }

    private void ColorButtonLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            if (_originalColors.ContainsKey(button))
            {
                button.BackColor = _originalColors[button];
            }

        }
    }

    private void ColorButtonEnter(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            _originalColors[button] = button.BackColor;
            button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is this:

```
public void ColorButtons(Button button)
 {
   button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }
```

Add this method to every mouse hover event. In your case this would be:

```
private void myButton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ColorButton(myButton);
 }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is just moving the problem somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom button.

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
     this.BackColor = Color.Blue;   // I am not sure this line but

     // you can set the background color here.
     // then you can use this class as a button
}
```