# ProcessCmdKey firing twice, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, richtextbox

I'm wondering why my ProcessCmdKey fires twice, when i press the button. Here's my code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                if (this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Focused)
                {
                    this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Text = this.startFontComboBoxText;
                    this.richTextBox.Focus();
                    this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Focus();
                    this.isEscClicked = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else if (this.tsComboBoxFontSizeChoice.Focused)
                {
                    this.tsComboBoxFontSizeChoice.Text = this.startFontSizeComboBoxText;
                    this.tsComboBoxFontSizeChoice.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

I have also defined KeyDown event for my form, might it be the reason?

And one more: if I would like to define KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPressed event for the RichTextBox, won't it collide with ProcessCmdKey? I've never overriden default methods, but this time I am forced to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason your `ProcessCmdKey` is firing multiple times is this:

> The ProcessCmdKey method first determines whether the control has a ContextMenu, and if so, enables the ContextMenu to process the command key. If the command key is not a menu shortcut and the control has a parent, the key is passed to the parent's ProcessCmdKey method. The net effect is that command keys are "bubbled" up the control hierarchy. In addition to the key the user pressed, the key data also indicates which, if any, modifier keys were pressed at the same time as the key. Modifier keys include the SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys.

per MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx

In your method there, I see you're checking which control is focused. So this method is firing for that control, then for the parent control (which I assume is the form) because it's unlikely that focused control has has a shortcut key or whatever.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just thought it is something wrong. And do you know if there is possibility to stop this net effect? I mean if I would like only ProcessCmdKey event be fired for the Focused control, not passing it to the parent (which you guessed is a form)?

Comment: I think for that you'd simply want to just use the appropriate key event

Comment: It is being called twice for a ComboBox while working fine for a TextBox though both are on a same group panel. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @bjan Not off the top of my head, no, but I haven't worked with WinForms since... shortly before I posted this answer. Give me a little bit to play with a demo app. But I think you might want to simply ask your own question, include your specific code and link this question as a "I did my research but this 'possible duplicate' didn't work"

Comment: @bjan I was able to duplicate the behavior you described. If I change my method to simply `return true;` rather than `return base.ProcessCmdKey(...);`, it only fires once for both controls. There might be some weird logic dictating how the `ComboBox` handles whatever key is being pressed, causing it to "bubble up" for the groupbox causing it to be sent a second time.

Comment: I was using `ProcessCmdKey` for validation. On failure it was showing the message twice. I just used `return true;` instead of `return base.ProcessCmdKey(...);` after the message. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: @bjan glad I could help, but as I said to Pawel you might want to consider using `KeyDown`,` KeyUp`, or `KeyPress` instead. I'm not sure what exactly are the implications of using `ProcessCmdKey` and "hard coding" it to `return true;` would be. If you have multiple controls which perform the same validation, you could consider [having multiple controls subscribe to same event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according) instead. That's how I would do it, anyways.