# Why does `ProcessCmdKey` fire twice for a combobox but once for a textbox?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a winforms application which contains 3 controls on my form: `GroupBox gb1` which contains `ComboBox cmb1` and `TextBox tb1`.

In `Form1.cs` I have the following code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (comboBox1.Focused)
        MessageBox.Show("Cmb Focus");
    else if (textBox1.Focused)
        MessageBox.Show("Txtbox Focus");

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

If I focus my textbox and press a key I get 1 MessageBox display. With the combobox focused, I get 2 popups.

I initially stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617960/processcmdkey-firing-twice-winforms/32618079?noredirect=1#comment71913986_32618079) a year and a half ago and the person who posted the question accepted my solution, which simply quotes MSDN:

> The ProcessCmdKey method first determines whether the control has a ContextMenu, and if so, enables the ContextMenu to process the command key. If the command key is not a menu shortcut and the control has a parent, the key is passed to the parent's ProcessCmdKey method. The net effect is that command keys are "bubbled" up the control hierarchy.

I understand what it's saying, but at the same time I don't understand the "actual" behavior of my application.

Neither control has a context menu. Both controls have 1 parent object (the group box). So why do they behave differently?

I tried a few things to help me understand:

**1)** If I change my code to `return true;`, both controls only display 1 message box. If I change it to `return false;`, I get the same behavior as described initially.

**2)** I thought that maybe it was a "side-effect" of the fact that the [Combobox object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.ListControl`. So I tried just adding a third control, a `ListBox`, which also inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.ListControl`. But when I focus this `ListBox` I still only get 1 messagebox.

**3)** I added `comboBox1.Items.Add("1");` to my `Form1()` constructor, then pressed the <kbd>1</kbd> key on my keyboard. I thought, "Maybe if I press a key 'corresponding to' an item in the combobox's `Items` collection, it'll only show 1 popup." But no, it still shows twice.

This behavior was brought to my attention yesterday after a user commented on the answer I posted in the question linked above but I haven't been able to figure out *why* this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit of a quirk, specific to ComboBox.  It [calls ProcessCmdKey as well](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,1644) in its message handler.  Not 100% sure why it does this, but almost certainly has something to do with the keystrokes received by the dropdown instead of the textbox.

Otherwise a side-effect of the way the native combobox processes messages, it forwards WM_KEYDOWN messages from the dropdown to the textbox if they were not used to select an item in the dropdown.   Described in "Default Combo Box Behavior" section of [the SDK doc page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775793(v=vs.85).aspx).  And there is no way to tell where it came from so Winforms can't make it selective.

Yes, you are certainly supposed to `return true;` when you process the keystroke, always necessary.  I can't tell why you skipped this but it does solve the problem.  Maybe IMessageFilter can solve your problem (didn't try it), but the question doesn't give any hint what the real problem looks like.

Comment: In regards to your last paragraph, I was mostly just going off the code in the question I linked, there the original poster calls the `base` method at the end of his `override`. I wasn't sure if it "was a good idea" to plainly `return true;` regardless of what the input was, in case this might modify the intended behavior of the control(s) / application.

Comment: Calling base.ProcessCmdKey() is a hard requirement or you'll break shortcut keystroke handling in the base class.  But not if you used the keystroke, the point of adding `return true;`