# Multiple OnClick events in c#

Tags: c#

I want to ask if i have multiple labels with same function Onclick but with different parameters. How i can handle them without make 30 methods.
I want to make A-Z Filter in windows forms application with C#. I have label for each character (A,B,C,D....,Z). Also i have TreeView with data from DB.

```
private void labelLetter1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.labelLetter1.Text
    // get value of the label and refresh treeview
}
```

I want to make this on every characters but without repeat same code.

Comment: What parameters? Please show us some of your labels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subscribe an example event to other ones. try like this:

```
private void labelLetter1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Label lbl = (Label) sender;
     var text = lbl.Text;
    //this.labelLetter1.Text
   // get value of the label and refresh treeview
 }
```

now set this event to other labels from Properties window.

Comment: Thanks ! This helped me !

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` parameter is going to be the original object that triggered the event. In your case, it is going to be a `Label`. This means you could cast the `object` to a `Label`.

Additionally you could make a single label_click method and have all labels user that single method.

For example:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String labelText = (sender as Label).Text;
    //Your process
}
```