# Common event handler for multiple controls of different types in C#

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I am creating a form with multiple fields: Textboxes, Checkboxes, DropBoxes Numeric UpDowns.

When form loads, I fetch the database and fill with existing data.

If user changes any field, I have to send that information to database.

Right now, I have one event for each control (3 `checkedChanged`, 4 `TextChanged`, 3 `ValueChanged` and 2 `SelectedIndexChanged`).

I have taken an array of `bool`, in which I set variable to True and change the back colour.

```
bool[] bChangedValues = new bool[12];

private void tbName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     tbName.BackColor = CHANGED_COLOUR;
     // Set the flag to true to indicate value is changed
     bChangedValues [Name_Index] = true;
}

private void chIEnable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     chIEnable.BackColor = CHANGED_COLOUR;
     // Set the flag to true to indicate value is changed
     bChangedValues [IEnable_Index] = true;
}
```

and so on...

When User will click on Save, I will parse this array and send commands to database with new values.

I realize that this is a bad implementation. A common event handler will be much easier.  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according) answer and found it suitable for my problem. But then how can I access properties like `BackColor` etc from `sender`?

I need a way to club multiple event handlers of different control typess in one and also access properties of the control in that event handler.

I am using C# .NetFramework 4.0

Comment: Cast sender to `Control` type: `((Control)sender).BackColor`. Thats controls inherit from `Control` and `Control` have `BackColor` property.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks!! Works perfectly!! This is why I love StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add name of the index to the `Tag` of control, then you can set `bChangedValues` too.

```
private void Control_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    control.BackColor = CHANGED_COLOUR;
    bChangedValues[control.Tag] = true;
}
```