# How to group all my buttons (Sudoku Game) c#

Tags: c#

i'm making my own sudoku game but i don't know where to start. 
I've created buttons but i don't know how to group them for creating a conditions
can anyone please help me. this is my project! thank you! I know this is a 9x9 set of boxes but i'm starting at first 9 boxes. this is my code or if anyone have they're own sudoku code please let me know so i can review it. thank you very much.

```
    private void b11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b11.Text = tbNum.Text;

        Algo = '1';

    }

    private void b18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b18.Text = tbNum.Text;

        Algo = '8';
    }

    private void b17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b17.Text = tbNum.Text;

        Algo = '7';
    }

    private void b16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b16.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '6';
    }

    private void b15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b15.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '5';
    }

    private void b14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b14.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '4';
    }

    private void b13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b13.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '3';
    }

    private void b12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b12.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '2';
    }

    private void b19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b19.Text = tbNum.Text;
        Algo = '9';
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You should not creat click for each button. Its a mess.

Comment: okay what should i do sir? what type of tools i should use?

Comment: You can call a single click event by all buttons and then get the sender.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3814247/2270492 might help

Comment: sudoku code chk out this link https://scottlilly.com/c-sudoku-solver-source-code/