# C# assigning several buttons to the same method

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, controls

I'm trying to build a simple game of 'HangMan' using Win8 GUI. I've build the GUI with 26 buttons on screen, each represent one letter of the alphabet.

I want to connect all the buttons to the same method that checks whatever the value of the button that was pressed matches one of the letter in the selected word.  I've looked at this question answers that supposed to help me in this but the one difference i think is that all the logic and methods in my game are on different class, the "Game Manager" class.

[How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according)

Plus i didnt quit understood how, using this solution the method which i will assign all the buttons to will know which button was pressed. I hope i explaind my situation clear enough, if not i can provide parts of the code for better understanding.

Comment: I would reverse the lingo: How to assign the same method to several buttons' event handlers. Answer: Just like doing it for one but always with the same method name. Then use the `sender` parameter (cast to Button) to discern which button has triggered the event..

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic method for what you want:

```
    static string key = "Level solution";
    char[] chars = key.ToCharArray();
    void check (object sender)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        character = Convert.ToChar(button.Text);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            //checks every character to mark them
            if (c == character)
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
                //Makes character unusable for later use

                //Anything you want now for true letters, for example showing pics or adding them to a label
            }
            i++;
        }
        //checks every character of key again, to see if player is won
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char c in chars) {
            if (c != ' ') count++;
            //Adds a number for anything expect space
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You won!");
        }

    }
```

You can paste it on top of your codes and then use just this code in any button:

```
check(sender);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But i still dont understand where the value of the clicked button enters so that this method or my would compare it to one of the chars of the word.   I registered all the buttons to one Event click that triggers the CheckLetter function in other class.  but how i pass the value of the button through this chain to match it using the method.

Comment: `private void CheckLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Mng.CheckLetter();
        }`   
`public bool CheckLetter()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtBlkArr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (btnA.Content == txtBlkArr[i])
                {
                    txtBlkArr[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                }
                else
                {
                    //StartHanging();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }`

Comment: Use edited method now. this one should do what you want. *Not tested yet

Comment: Thank you! i understand now, finally someone just explains and let me learn new things insted of downvoting and doing nothing.  i apllied the 'Var button = sender as Button' to my code and that exactly what i wanted!

Comment: You're welcome dude, Downvoting XD. there are always people downvote everything without reading :P

Comment: Don't you wanna just accept the answer if it was right? or a vote?