# Write code for all buttons click

Tags: c#, winforms, button

There is a code to download the text from URL

```
string url = textBox1.Text;
string address = @url;
string newText = null;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        newText = reader.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
    }
}
```

I tried to make a windows form app and there are many buttons and each one contain same code, and each press button takes a 20 second

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // same code for  download text
    // some code where I use only "newText"
}
```

how can I write "download code" at once and see all button "newText"?

Comment: You can assign the same Event Handler to each buttons Click event. That way, the exact same code will be run no matter which button is pressed

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want every button to execute the same code, you can set the button click event handler for each button to point to the same method. You can find this in the form designer (C# code, not the visual designer).

Comment: In `designer`, select all buttons, go to `Properties` window, click `Events`, double click at `Click`. By this way all button's click event will be same function.

Comment: Put download code to a function and call it where you need.

Comment: you can find the answer of this with other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same code to be used from different event handlers, you can just create a method:

```
public string GetNewText(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your event handler you call the method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newText = GetNewText(textBox1.Text);
    // do something with newText
}
```

If you truly want to run *exactly* the same code for all buttons, and nothing more, you could assign the same event handler to their `Click` events. However I would reconsider the user interface design in that case.