# How to check if multiple buttons where clicked in an alphabet soup game

Tags: c#

everyone

I have this assignment at school where I have to make one of those alphabet puzzle games where you find a word in an alphabet soup. I don't really know the name for it.

I have 70 buttons. For example button12, button13, button14 and button 14 form the word "HOLA". As soon as people click those four buttons I want them (those four buttons) to be disabled, except if people clicked on another button which wasn't part of the word. I know I could program each button assigning a value to a variable and upping that value when I click the button. The problem is that I'd prefer not to do this on all 70 buttons since there are other requirements for the assignment and the code would be too long.

I tried a bunch of stuff but I've since then erased the code out of frustration.

This is an image of my form: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNMsF.png)

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button myButton = (Button)sender;

        myButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    }
```

I have that event in all my buttons because I have to change the text color on each button when I click on them.

Edit: I did put all the buttons manually

Comment: How do you populate the form? did you manually put 70 buttons on page? OR did you usa kind of algorithm to create them?

Comment: I guess you really need to do this on every button... Otherwise, if you have the same method on every button take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create buttons and assign event hadlers in a *loop*:

```
  for (int line = 0; line < 7; ++line) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 10; ++column) {
      Button button = new Button() {
        Parent = this,
        Text = "?", // Here you to generate button's text, e.g. with Random   
        Location = new Point(50 + line * 40, 50 + column * 40),
        Size = new Size(30, 30),
      };

      button.Click += (ss, ee) => {
        Button myButton = ss as Button;

        myButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      };
    }
  }
```

If you put all the buttons on the form *manually*, you can assign event hadlers in a loop as well:

```
  foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
    button.Click += (ss, ee) => {
      Button myButton = ss as Button;

      myButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    };
  }
```

Comment: This works only if you want to execute the same functionality on all buttons (Except you include some checks on the button name or so, e.g. if the name is button1 `doThis()` and if the name is button2 `doThat()`)

Comment: @FranzHuber23: according to the image provided in the question all `70` buttons are peers

Comment: Oww this must be so frustrating for Rene Vazquez.. but the work is done, so Dimitri's create loop is not needed. Agree with Franz on the second part of Dimitri's solution.. it assigns ALL. if there are (or will be) buttons for other things, you would assign them too. I would move all buttons in a group box "game" and test for Parent, before the event is set. And you could also use  the Tag property of each button, to mark game things. This is a school assignment.. so I'm not gonna spell it out ! Success Rene !

Comment: `And you could also use the Tag property of each button` That's what I meant with seperating between different buttons. Sure, you can use the tag. Is probably the easist way to do so.