# VSTO Ribbon - general/abstract button click event?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

In a C# VSTO Ribbon, you can design and place buttons and you can program whatever you want each button to do i.e. an action that will occur on each individual button click event can be defined by the programmer.

I have some code I would like to perform every time a button was clicked -
 regardless of which button was clicked. A simple example includes measuring the time that the button click event was received: I want this for all my buttons, so, I am looking for a general / abstract event handling all button clicks or something of the sort rather than each event one by one. Does this exist in VSTO or is there a clean implementation to it?

Here is a simple illustration of the problem in code.

I have 3 buttons: btn1, btn2 and btn3. And I have defined what I will do for each click as follows:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   //same code
   //btn1 specific code
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   //same code
   //btn2 specific code
}

private void btn3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   //same code
   //btn3 specific code
}
```

The problem is clear: there is part of the code that I want to do that is the same for each click. So is there a general click event where I can define the same code only just once?

Comment: You have two broad options. 1) Write a new function (let's call it `Bob`) and change all of your `//same code` to instead by `Bob();`. 2) Wire up an event handler manually for `btn1` through to `btn2` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according).

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 will block the rest of my code (if I don't put it on a new thread of course). I am assuming option 2 won't. Is this correct? In any case, I will try it out.

Comment: Both will block. Unless you create a new thread / task then the code will execute on the UI thread.

Comment: Of course that things will block if there is not a seperate thread. However, I thought that since there can possibly be more than one event attached to a click, that these execute in parallel under the hood.

Comment: No they won't be in parallel.