# winform add same event handler to multiple checkbox not found

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help with subscribing multiple checkbox to same function.  Trying to copy this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814247/3015268 However it says functionName not found when I try.

> The type or namespace name "GroupCheckBoxClick' could not be found

```
void GroupCheckBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//
private void setGroupChkBox(bool loadedFromDataRow)
{

    List<CheckBox> ApplyRewardCalcList = new List<CheckBox> { ckBxARC1, ckBxARC2, ckBxARC3, ckBxARC4, ckBxARC5, ckBxARC6, ckBxARC7, ckBxARC8, ckBxARC9, ckBxARC10};
    List<CheckBox> FixedGroupPromoList = new List<CheckBox> { ckBxFGP1, ckBxFGP2, ckBxFGP3, ckBxFGP4, ckBxFGP5, ckBxFGP6, ckBxFGP7, ckBxFGP8, ckBxFGP9, ckBxFGP10};

    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
    {
        //says GroupCheckBoxClick type or namespace not found
        ApplyRewardCalcList[r].MouseDown += new GroupCheckBoxClick;

    }
```

Comment: GroupCheckBoxClick is a function, not a delegate. You need something like: `ApplyRewardCalcList[r].MouseDown += new System.EventHandler(GroupCheckBoxClick);`

Comment: Or you can just drop the new, IE: `ApplyRewardCalcList[r].MouseDown += GroupCheckBoxClick;`

Comment: Why doesn't function work though?  I copied from another answer see edit.

Comment: It does if you drop the 'new' keyword. You can't 'new' a function. You can new a delegate (which is what System.EventHandler is). (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-5.0). If you drop the 'new' and just do the function name, the compiler just shortcuts the `new System.EventHandler(MethodName);` for you.

Comment: I see anyways yes it fixed the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code

- After `+=`, type only the name of the procedure, not `new`
- The signature of your procedure must match the delegate of the event. In this case it is a [MouseEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler?view=net-5.0) which has the following signature:

  public delegate void MouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);

So your event handler must match this signature:

```
private void CheckBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {...}
```

Pay attention to the type of the MouseEventArgs!

```
IEnumerable<CheckBox> checkBoxesInMyGroup = ...

foreach (CheckBox checkBox in checkBoxesInMyGroup)
{
    checkBox.MouseDown += CheckBox_MouseDown;
}

private void CheckBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;

    // use the mouse event args to handle the mouse down on this checkbox
    this.ProcessMouseDown(checkBox, e);
}
```

> Tip: in visual studio, after typing the `+=`, type `<tab>` to let visual studio insert the proper event handler. You can change the name of the method and move the code later.

As you will subscribe several CheckBoxes to the same event handler, you will have to find out which CheckBox was clicked:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
```

Since you have declared the event handler private, you know that no one outside your class can have subscribed: your class controls who can subscribe to the event, so you can be certain that the sender is a CheckBox.

Finally: are you sure you want to react on mouse down, not on  mouse click? Sometimes the operator puts the mouse down, and realizes that he made a mistake. He can move the mouse away before mouse up to cancel the mouse click. If you react on mouse down, the operator can't handle these kind of mistakes.