# How does one create an indexed event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

For various reasons I need to create an array of controls (in this case buttons which represent relays). This I've managed to do at runtime as follows:

```
private Button[] butRelays = new Button[8];

for (i = 0; i < butRelays.Length; ++i)
{
    butRelays[i] = new Button();
    butRelays[i].Text = "R" + (i + 1);
    butRelays[i].Width = 31;
    butRelays[i].Height = 62;
    butRelays[i].Top = 19;
    butRelays[i].Left = 6 + 30 * i;
    grpRelays.Controls.Add(butRelays[i]);
    this.butRelays[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.butRelays_Click);
}
```

The problem is, how does one create a separate indexed event handler for each button or otherwise how can one distinguish between the different buttons in the same event handler? The following would be ideal if it were actually allowed:

```
this.butRelays[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.butRelays[i]_Click);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I subscribe multiple buttons to the same event handler and act according to what button was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814234/how-can-i-subscribe-multiple-buttons-to-the-same-event-handler-and-act-according)

Comment: There's also a `Tag` property on controls which is useful for determining the clicked button (If you dont want to use `Text` for example)

Comment: In event handler read the text value of the button.  The event handler would have instruction : Button button =  sender as Button

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from an object like this.

```
private void OnBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonText = (sender as Button).Text;
}
```