# How to change properties just one button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, buttonclick

Hey,
I have multiple buttons.I want to reduce the code so that I can set the properties of a button, but only the one I click on will change.So that I don't click on button_1 and change all the others

```
 public static void SetProp()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                buttons[i].Image = Properties.Resources.test;
                buttons[i].Width = buttons[i].Image.Width;
                buttons[i].Height = buttons[i].Image.Height;
                buttons[i].ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                buttons[i].Text = null;
                GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
                gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, buttons[i].Width, buttons[i].Height);
                buttons[i].Region = new Region(gp);
                gp.Dispose();
            }
        }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetProp();
          

        }
```

Comment: If I understand your question - you need to do something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814247/1928632

Comment: `SetProp(sender as Button);`

Comment: @Jimi And what this does?Because it works and I would like to know how does this work or mean

Comment: When a Control raises an event, the Event Handler's `sender` Object references the Control that raised the event. So, if all your Controls subscribe to the an event using the same Event Handler, you can discriminate the Control that raised the event casting `sender` to `Control` or the specific Type of Control (`Button`, in this case), if you need to get/set properties specific to that Type.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void SetProp(Button button)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                button.Image = Properties.Resources.test;
                button.Width = buttons[i].Image.Width;
                button.Height = buttons[i].Image.Height;
                button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                button.Text = null;
                GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
                gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, button.Width, button.Height);
                button.Region = new Region(gp);
                gp.Dispose();
            }
        }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetProp(sender as Button);
           
          
        }
```

Comment: You don't need a loop there and `Properties.Resources.test` should be assigned to a Field of Type Image, otherwise you create a new Image object each time, without disposing of the previous.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).